# Problem finding the flux over a cylinder

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, divergence-operator

I'm doing this exercise:

> Let's consider the vector field given by $\mathbf F(x,y,z)=(x+1,y-1,1-2z)$,and the cylinder given by $S=\{x^2+y^2=1\mid\ 0≤z≤1 \}$, with the orientation given by $\mathbf{n}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}(x,y,0)$. Calculate the flux over the surface $S$ **integrating the divergence over a situable domain**.

My try:

> If we calculate the divergence and we use the Gauss theorem, we see that $$\iint_{S}\mathbf  F\cdot dS=\iiint_V\operatorname{div}(\mathbf F)\,dV$$
>   but $\operatorname{div}(\mathbf F)=1+1-2,$ so the flux over any surface is $0$.

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The surface $S$ is not the entire boundary of $V$.  To use the divergence theorem, you have to close up $S$ by adding the top and bottom disks.  Let
\begin{align*}
    S_1 &= \left\{(x,y,1)\mid x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \right\} \\
    S_0 &= \left\{(x,y,0)\mid x^2 + y^2 \leq 1 \right\} \\
\end{align*}
So as surfaces,
$$
    \partial V =  S \cup S_1 \cup S_0
$$

Now we need to orient those surfaces.  The conventional way to orient a surface that is the graph of a function is “upwards”—that is, the normal direction with positive $z$-component.  So $\mathbf{n} = \mathbf{k}$ on $S_0$ and $S_1$.  The conventional way to orient a surface that is the boundary of a solid is “outwards.”  On $S_1$, upwards and outwards are the same, but on $S_0$, upwards and outwards are opposite.  So we say
$$
    \partial V = S + S_1 - S_0
$$
as *oriented* surfaces. Therefore
\begin{align*}
    \iiint_V \operatorname{div}\mathbf{F}\,dV 
    &= \iint_{\partial V} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S}
  \\&= \iint_{S + S_1 - S_0} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S}
  \\&= \iint_S \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S} + \iint_{S_1} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S} - \iint_{S_0} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S}
\end{align*}
The three integrals on the right are no longer thought of as attached to $V$.
In particular, $S_1$ and $S_0$ are both oriented upwards now.
We can solve this for $\iint_S \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S}$:
$$
    \iint_S \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S}
    = \iiint_V \operatorname{div}\mathbf{F}\,dV 
     -\iint_{S_1} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S}
     +\iint_{S_0} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S}
$$
As you point out, the first integral on the right-hand side is zero.  On the surface $S_1$, $\mathbf{n} = \mathbf{k}$ and $\mathbf{F} = \left<x+1,y-1,-1\right>$.  So
$$
    \iint_{S_1} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S}
   =\iint_{S_1} \left<x+1,y-1,-1\right>\cdot \mathbf{k}\,dS
   =\iint_{S_1} (-1)\,dS = (-1) \operatorname{Area}(S_1) = -\pi
$$
On $S_2$, $\mathbf{F} = \left<x+1,y-1,1\right>$, so
$$
    \iint_{S_0} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S}
   =\iint_{S_0} 1\,dS = \operatorname{Area}(S_1) = \pi
$$
Putting these all together, we have
$$
  \iint_S \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S} = 2\pi
$$

---

In this case, it's possible to check the calculation by computing the flux directly.  Parametrize the surface $S$ by
$$
   \mathbf{r}(u,v) = \left<\cos u,\sin u, v\right>
$$
over $0 \leq u \leq 2\pi$, $0 \leq v \leq 1$.  Then
$$
   \mathbf{n} = \left<\cos u,\sin u,0\right>
$$
So
\begin{align*}
    \iint_S \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S}
    &= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \left<\cos u+1,\sin u-1, v\right>\cdot \left<\cos u,\sin u,0\right>\,dv\,du \\
    &= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \left(\cos^2 u+\cos u +\sin^2 u-\sin u\right)\,dv\,du \\
    &= \int_0^{2\pi} \left(\cos^2 u+\cos u +\sin^2 u-\sin u\right)\,du \\
    &= \int_0^{2\pi} \left(1+\cos u -\sin u\right)\,du \\
    &= 2\pi + 0 - 0 = 2\pi
\end{align*}

Comment: Okay, I have 2 questions now: How do you decide in which direction you take **n** on $S_1$ and $S_0$? And why did you decide to add the $S_1$ integral and take out the $S_0$ one?

If I understood it correctly, we should have:

$$\iint_S \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S}
    = \iiint_V \operatorname{div}\mathbf{F}\,dV 
     -\iint_{S_1} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S}
     -\iint_{S_0} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{S}$$

right?

On $S_0$, the normal it's $\mathbf{n} = \mathbf{-k}$, and then the integral over $S_0$ is $-\pi$, giving when you add up everything, $2\cdot\pi$

Comment: Those are the right questions.  Let me edit the answer.

Comment: I understand your solution now! Then, the solution I pointed out in my comment is also correct?

Comment: @Relure: Yes, yours is right, too.  It's just that your $S_0$ and mine are oriented oppositely, so the minus signs cancel.

Comment: matthew isn't $Z=0$ and $Z=1$ the required discs(planes) for closing the region and applying Divergence theorem?

Comment: @Upstart yes, which is what I did. Notice $S_0 = V \cap \{ z=0 \}$ and $S_1 = V \cap \{ z=1 \}$.

Comment: Can u tell me why u added S1 and substracted S0... Did u draw the vector field and then deduced this or is there an intuition. Please help!!

Comment: Or is it because the normal vector is positive for one surface and negative for other hence the cancel

Comment: @Aladdin It doesn't have anything to do with the vector field being integrated; it's all about orientation.  Reread the paragraph above that equation.

Comment: I am somewhat confused between these two terms: graph of function and boundry of solid. Aren't they same but you have used it as different terms

Comment: @Aladdin no, in this case $S$ is part of the boundary of the solid $V$, but it is not the graph of a function.